# Solutions to E. T. Jaynes Probability Theory for self study?

Tags: references

I am doing a self study of E.T.Jayne's Probability Theory, the logic of science. I wanted to see that does any one know of a web page providing solutions to the exercises? I have no teacher or anyone experienced in this book around me, I need to make sure that my solutions to them are correct.

Comment: The textbook Probability Theory: The Logic of Science is an interesting book if you already have read other probability and Bayesian statistics books, but if you are trying to teach yourself probability and/or Bayesian statistics by self study, I would suggest other books.  Bayesian Data analysis by Gelman et al is a solid Bayesian textbook with answers to many exercises on his website.  For probability theory, it is hard to recommend a textbook without knowing your mathematical background.

Comment: I wanted to start with Gelman et al. But in the introduction they have said that we will only be dealing with the practical aspects of Bayesian Data Analysis, not its philosophy. I am interested learning the core foundations of it, before learning its practical usage. I have read the first three chapters and I am really enjoying Jaynes's book. I just feel unsure about some of my solutions to the exercises and I keep on wondering if what I have done is correct or the most efficient way to do them. I am a graduate student with an undergraduate in Physics, so I feel I have the background.

Comment: It's OK to post your solutions here and ask for comments.

Comment: Great. I will write down all my solutions and when complete share them on a webpage and give the link here. Then Everyone interested can comment on them and correct them if they are wrong. Ultimately this will help future people like me who want self-study this great work. Is this a good way?

Comment: Of course in the meantime, if I cannot solve some, I will ask them individually as separate questions.

Comment: You may find some of the [solutions here](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/pr/jaynes.html). After reading them, I really don't thinking the exercises are helpful for self-study.

Comment: See also the following website: https://github.com/MaksimIM/JaynesProbabilityTheory